# How to Create a Linq Query with Multiple Conditional Where Clauses

Tags: linq

I have a linq query with multiple conditional where clauses. The query returns all data in the table when there is no filter in the where clause. How to make the linq query returns 0 record in the first time when there is no filter in the where clause? See my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using API.Models;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace API.Controllers
{
```

//api code starts here

```
public class MYTABLEController : ApiController
{
    private DataModel db = new DataModel();



    //GET /MYTABLE
    public List<MYTABLE> Get(string filter1 = null,string filter2=null)
    {

        IQueryable<MYTABLE> qry = db.MYTABLE.AsQueryable();
        var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MYTABLE>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter1))
        {

            searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(a => a.COLUMN1==(filter1);

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter2))
        {

            searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(a => a.COLUMN2==(filter2);

        }

        return qry.Where(searchPredicate).ToList();

    }
```

//PredicateBuilder https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

```
      public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a predicate that evaluates to true.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return param => true; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a predicate that evaluates to false.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return param => false; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a predicate expression from the specified lambda expression.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) { return predicate; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "and".
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.AndAlso);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "or".
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.OrElse);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Negates the predicate.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        var negated = Expression.Not(expression.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(negated, expression.Parameters);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the first expression with the second using the specified merge function.
    /// </summary>
    static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
    {
        // zip parameters (map from parameters of second to parameters of first)
        var map = first.Parameters
            .Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] })
            .ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

        // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with the parameters in the first
        var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

        // create a merged lambda expression with parameters from the first expression
        return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
    }

    class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map;

        ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
        {
            this.map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
        }

        public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
        {
            return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
        {
            ParameterExpression replacement;

            if (map.TryGetValue(p, out replacement))
            {
                p = replacement;
            }

            return base.VisitParameter(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By only creating the query if you have a filter

Comment: Okay, so I should move var Qry = (from a in db.myTable
           select a); into each if condition.

Comment: No not into each condition.

Comment: This way works and I cannot think about another way to do it now. I am trying to create an API. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this method like this:

```
public List<MYTABLE> Get(string filter1 = null,string filter2=null)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter2))
        return new List<MYTABLE>();

    IQueryable<MYTABLE> qry = db.MYTABLE.AsQueryable();
    var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MYTABLE>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter1))
    {
        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(a => a.COLUMN1==(filter1);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter2))
    {
        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(a => a.COLUMN2==(filter2);
    }
    return qry.Where(searchPredicate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What if there are `n` filters of different data types?

Comment: Thanks. I tried and received error message "System.NotSupportedException: 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'". The code works when there is no filter but errors out if passing in filters.

Comment: never mind. I used predicateBuilder code at this link and it works now. https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

Comment: OK, your choice, but the starting point `PredicateBuilder.False<MYTABLE>()` is wrong, should be `True`. And of course this makes it harder to add, and check, more predicates later.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd use a predicate builder for this. For example [this one](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

That would turn your code into:

```cs
IQyeryable<MyTable> qry = db.myTable;
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MyTable>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter1))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(a => a.column1.Contains(filter1));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter2))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(a => a.column2.Contains(filter2));
}
...

qry = qry.Where(predicate);
```

Now it's easy to check if any predicates were added. If not, `predicate` is nothing but `a => true`, which means that its body is just a `ConstantExpression` (value: `true`). You can add this check just above the last line:

```cs
if (predicate.Body is ConstantExpression)
{
    predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MyTable>();
}
```

(Of course provided that you don't *replace* `predicate` by another predicate, another constant expression, but I guess that wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: Thanks. But I got this error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: That's because you're using Linqkit's predicate builder. It requires `qry.AsExpandable()` or `predicate.Expand()` as you can see [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). That's why I prefer the predicate builder I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

And use it in a following fashion:

```
using static System.String;

...

public List<MYTABLE> Get(string filter1 = null,string filter2=null)
{
    return db.MYTABLE
       .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(filter1), y => y.COLUMN1 == filter1)
       .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(filter2), y => y.COLUMN2 == filter2)
       .ToList();
}
```